# How to show only particular object properties in AutoComplete of selected object instead of [object] in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular7

I'm working on a Angluar 7 project with Angular-Material and I'm using reactive forms the first time. I've implemented an AutoComplete so the user can select an employee from a list of EmployeeObjects. The form uses Angular reactive forms. The objects of the employees are much more complex than the user needs to know.

The selection of an employee and the storing and updating of the reactive form works fine. The problem is that the shown value in the input field looks like [object: object], because the whole object will set to the [value] of the input field.

When I implement a getter to show only the employee name the shown value looks correct, but the reactive form value only stores the formatted string instead of the whole object.

How is it possible to do both, show the correct string to the user and store the whole value in the form?

Thanks for your help.

**Stackblitz**

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-employee?file=app%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.html**

[image]

**Class**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-data',
  templateUrl: './employee-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-data.component.scss']
})
export class EmployeeDataComponent implements OnInit {

  employeeForm: FormGroup;
  employeeCtrl = new FormControl();
  employees: Employee[] = EmployeeList as Employee[];
  filteredEmployees: Observable<Employee[]>;
  result;
  @Input() employee: Employee;
  @ViewChild(MatAutocomplete) matAutocomplete: MatAutocomplete;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.initEmployeeFilters(this.employeeCtrl);
    this.employeeForm = this.createFormGroupWithBuilder(formBuilder);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  private _filterStates(value: string): Employee[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.employees.filter(employee => employee.lastname.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }

  public getFullname(employee: Employee): string {
    return employee.lastname + ', ' + employee.firstname;
  }

  public getEmployee(): Employee {
    return JOHN_DOE;
  }

  private initEmployeeFilters(formCtrl: FormControl) {
    this.filteredEmployees = formCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(employee => employee ? this._filterStates(employee) : this.employees.slice())
      );
  }

  createFormGroupWithBuilder(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    return formBuilder.group({
      employeeData: formBuilder.group({
        employee: new FormControl(),
      }),
    });
  }

  revert() {
    this.employeeForm.reset();
    this.employeeForm.reset({ employeeData: new Employee() });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.result = Object.assign({}, this.employeeForm.value);
    this.result.employeeData = Object.assign({}, this.result.employeeData);
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<form [formGroup]=„employeeForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
  <div formGroupName="employeeData" novalidate>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input
          matInput
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
          [matAutocomplete]="auto"
          formControlName="name"
        >
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option
            *ngFor="let employee of employees | async"
            [value]="getEmployee(employee)"
          >
            <img
              [src]="employee.profilePicture"
              height="25"
            >
            <span>{{employee.lastname}}, {{employee.firstname}}</span>
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="employeeForm.pristine">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Employee class and List of Employees**

```
export class Employee {
  id = 1;
  lastname = '';
  firstname = '';
}

export const JANE_DOE = {
    id: 1,
    lastname: 'Doe',
    firstname: 'Jane',
    profilePicture: ‚url‘
};

export const JOHN_DOE = {
    id: 2,
    lastname: 'Doe',
    firstname: 'John',
    profilePicture: ‚url‘
};

export const EmployeeList: Employee[] = [
    JANE_DOE,
    JOHN_DOE,
];
```

Comment: What is your expected output? can you provide a screenshot? I think you can use {{value | json }} to view the response

Comment: The output should show the Lastname, Firstname of an employee, not the [object].

Comment: @SkyHigh No, there're no errors

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I'm already using {{ employeeForm.value | json }} to see what's in the form. But I need the string values within the input field and there I've to set the selected value, which is a object of the list.

Comment: Can you produce the StackBlitz so I can try on it

Comment: Is that all you need? --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jnzox2?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.html

Comment: @kulosos check mine first! is that what you looking for? --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jnzox2?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.html

Comment: @PrashantPimpale No this is not exactly what I need. I need to save the choosen object to the reactive form as whole object, but I want to show only the name in the InputField. When I'm doing it your suggested way it will only save the name to the form, not the object.

Comment: I am not sure about will you get it or not [jst test] but you can do like this --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzdngr?file=app%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.html

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I updated my post and produced a stackblitz. I hope now it will be more clear what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `displayWith` input on mat-autocomplete to accomplish this.

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="valueMapper">
```

Then in your component

```
public valueMapper = (key) => {
  return key.firstname + ' ' + key.lastname;
};
```

Comment: Ah, obviously this is the official way to do that: 
https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values